# Overlapping features within a layer

Tags: overlapping-features, qgis-3

I have a shapefile in which polygons overlap and I can't have overlaps for the sake of my analysis. I want the overlapping area saved, but if the overlapping area is saved to the polygon with the smallest/largest area or shared boundary, doesn't matter much.

Merging manually is not an option, as I have tens of thousands polygons. Dissolve does solve a majority of the overlaps, but not all as I need to dissolve on an attribute I need to keep (and there is a range of values for this attribute).

I have tried SAGA polygon self-intersection tool, and it has worked for a similar previous problem, but not this time.

(The polygons are doughnuts created by the buffer & symmetrical difference tools, if it matters. My aim is to have a layer with doughnuts with no overlaps and as many doughnuts as plots, as I am going to run a regression clustering on "pairs" of doughnuts and plots.)